# Aligning content (image) used in radio button so that button wont show

Tags: html, forms, css, css-content

I currently have two radio buttons in a form that I have used the CSS property content to insert an image for each button and that changes in opacity when selected or not. The original radio button still shows to the left of the image. Is there any way move the image so that it is centered over the original radio button?

```
#button1,
#button2 {
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   margin-left: 10%;
   margin-right: 10%;
}

#button1 {
   content: url(../assets/logo.gif);
   opacity: .4;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 1.5s;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the image to be a "label" for the button and not see it, and only the image? Only see the button2?

Comment: use `text-align:center;`

Comment: I basically want to use the image to replace the button and have it change opacity depending on when it selected or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xtPhw/) is what you're looking for.

HTML

```
<label class="mickey" for="button1">
      <input id="button1" type="radio" name="testme" />
      <img src='http://i.imgur.com/Q7IJUNJ.png?1' alt='' />
</label>

<label class="mickey" for="button2">
      <input id="button2" type="radio" name="testme" />
      <img src='http://i.imgur.com/73kXZTR.jpg' alt='' />
</label>
```

CSS

```
#button1, #button2 {
    display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + img{
  cursor:pointer;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + img {
  border: 2px solid red;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```